# permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@tendermint/starport/tmp-167254-vA18laJne7zO'

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, tendermint, starport

I am trying to install `@tendermint/starport`:

```
npm i -g @tendermint/starport
```

I get this error:

```
 EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@tendermint/starport/tmp-167254-vA18laJne7zO'
```

I am executing the command as superuser.

What is the problem here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to install [Starport](https://github.com/tendermint/starport) is to use the following command:

```
curl https://i.jpillora.com/tendermint/starport! | bash
```

It will use a [script](https://github.com/jpillora/installer) to download the binary and install it in `/usr/local/bin`. On macOS you can also use Homebrew:

```
brew install tendermint/tap/starport
```